# Exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.StringEx'

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines

My unit tests run fine on my local where i am using visual studio 2022. But when i run the same in pipeline it gives me the following error

##[error]An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.StringEx' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

This is the complete stack trace

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.StringEx' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
##[error]Stack trace:
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Stack trace:
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestSettings.PopulateSettings(IDiscoveryContext context)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestSettings.PopulateSettings(IDiscoveryContext context)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle) ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionDecorators.SerialTestRunDecorator.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle) ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.ExtensionDecorators.SerialTestRunDecorator.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.RunTestsWithSources.InvokeExecutor(LazyExtension`2 executor, Tuple`2 executorUriExtensionTuple, RunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.RunTestsWithSources.InvokeExecutor(LazyExtension`2 executor, Tuple`2 executorUriExtensionTuple, RunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.b__0()
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.b__0()
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
##[error]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
##[error]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.Run(Action action, PlatformApartmentState apartmentState, Boolean waitForCompletion)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformThread.Run(Action action, PlatformApartmentState apartmentState, Boolean waitForCompletion)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.TryToRunInStaThread(Action action, Boolean waitForCompletion)
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.TryToRunInStaThread(Action action, Boolean waitForCompletion)
##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(IEnumerable`1 executorUriExtensionMap, Int64 totalTests) ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(IEnumerable`1 executorUriExtensionMap, Int64 totalTests)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Framework 4.8.4300.0)

This is the step in the pipeline

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run unit tests'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.enableTests }}', 'true'))
  inputs:
  #vstestLocationMethod: location
  #vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Microsoft.TestPlatform.16.4.0\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform'
  #vstestLocation: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform'
  testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
  vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
  testAssemblyVer2: '**\*UnitTests*.dll'
  platform: '${{ parameters.buildPlatform }}'
  configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
  searchFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\${{parameters.packageFolderName}}'
  codeCoverageEnabled: '${{ parameters.enableCodeCoverage }}'
  runInParallel: "true"
  testFiltercriteria: "TestCategory!=Manual"

I tried changing the versions of the MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework and also .NET SDK as suggested by different answers of the similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround solution for it, in my azure pipeline instead of using VStest@2 task, I used DotNetCoreCLI@2 task and it solved the problem

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Run unit tests'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.enableTests }}', 'true'))
    inputs:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run unit tests'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.enableTests }}', 'true'))
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case our unit test project had both the MSTest.TestAdapter and NUnit3TestAdapter packages installed.

It was a set of NUnit tests, and removing the reference to MSTest.TestAdapter resolved the exception.

(Incidentally, we saw the exception under both VSTest (and VSTest.Console.exe) and dotnet.exe test.)